# Referencing indirect dependencies in nuget

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

Looks like this is trivial question but somehow I can't figure it out.

Let's suppose very easy case: App A references Library B which in turn references Library C.

Now, when I try to run App A and it invokes Library B in code I get runtime exception that referenced Library C could not be loaded. This is obvius, can be fixed by either a) referencing library C in App A so that it is added in Bin folder or preferrably b)adding it to GAC.

I would like to ask - is there any way to automatically resolve such dependencies?

Comment: Normally this works automatically - we need more details about what kind of application you're building, how you're building it, how you're running it, which version of .NET you're using etc.

Comment: Thanks for answer @JonSkeet. Let me create sample solution so that issue is reproducinble, will do it a bit later. For now I can say that I am using .Net 4.5, it's windows servide app, built using msbuild by passing solution name, no other actions.